# How to authenticate tenant in Azure Function based on Route

Tags: azure, authentication, routes, azure-functions, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenant app on Azure. The app collects data from the IOT Hub and summarizes the device data by tenant. I want each tenant to be able to view their devices' summaries.

To collect the device data from the IOT Hub, I have a Function that gets the device data, summarises it and stores it in an Azure Table where PartionKey = tenantId and RowKey = DeviceId.

To enable tenants to view their device summaries, I have a HTTP GET Triggered Azure Function with a route specified as:
https://.azurewebsites.net/api/tenant/{tenantId}/deviceSummary
The tenantId is of course bound to the function input parameter.

In the function I query the Azure table where PartionKey = tenantId.

Obviously I need to prevent tenants from using the Get function to access other tenants' data. I.e. validate the tenant's route somehow.

The first idea was to create a function key for each tenant using the tenantId as the key name. Then, when handling the request, I obtain the passed in key, and using the KeyStore API, validate that the key (code) in the request matches the key corresponding to the tenantId in the route.

The above is my (ignorant) idea of how to do this. What is the 'right' way?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how many Function Keys you can generate so if you have a high volume of customers/tenants that could be an issue.

Function Proxies are worth exploring as you could provide a different URL & parameter order from your function through the proxy and then translate that into your functions expected format.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies.

Azure API Management (increases cost) would be able to provide a gateway/façade that would allow you to have different URL paths/parameters all pointing to the same Azure Function.  Might be more than you need if this is a smaller system but worth looking into.  It will also provide some other nice benefits (Operation IP Filtering, policies, metering, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. We will not have many tenants, so I think the number of keys should not be an issue. I think proxies is also a good suggestion that I will look into.

Comment: Had a look at proxies but not sure how that solves the problem. If my Function url is https://abc.azurewebsites.net/api/tenant/{tenantId}/deviceSummary then I could create a proxy in the form https://abc.azurewebsites.net//{tenantName}/deviceSummary that will call the backend url with tenant id. But I would have to have a proxy for each tenant and nothing would prevent a tenant from trying another tenant URL. Maybe i am missing something?

Comment: Well if you switch to a generic key for your users that would provide a little bit of difficulty to guess.  (i.e. abc.azurewebsites.net/{Key}/deviceSummary that then gets proxied to a specific function and function key with parameters)   Someone would have to guess the key you gave to each consumer.  Just a quick thought...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'right' way you're looking for is **Azure App Service Authentication** or **EasyAuth**. **Azure Functions** are built on the same underlying core components as **Azure App Services** so you can use the same authentication mechanism.

I would refer to this [blog post on Azure Functions and App Service Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/) and in the Azure App Services Documentation, under the Security section: [Authentication and Authorization documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

Comment: Thanks i will look into this